# Jersey ApplicationEventListener does not work

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey

I created ApplicationEventListener as described [there](http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#monitoring). I annoptated it with @Provider and registered it with:

```
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
```

I packaged my application into war archive and deploy in Glassfish, Jersey registered filter and class with Jersey annotations (I can see it in logs). Jersey request works, but ApplicationEventListener  code does not work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
  <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;com.github.pires.example.rest.providers.SimpleApplicationEventListener</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You must remove the @Provider annotation. See the [full example source-code](https://github.com/pires/simple-jersey-rest-app).

Comment: Thank you it is working as you mentioned
This webpage may become helpful
https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e16007